# File Not found exception in the master of a COMPSs application

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I am running an application implemented with COMPSs and I am getting the following error in the application standard output.

```
...    
[(2016-07-27 11:47:34,255)    API]  -  No more tasks for app 1

[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Error master local copying file /home/compss/tmp/localhost/f5e5af5d-c2e4-4fa2-be7f-eca342207ec3/localhost/d866v2_1469612848882.IT from master to workspace_java/guidance_0.9.8/tests/test_1/outputs/associations/phenoA/EURvsAFR_for_1kg/Chr_21/chr_21_phenoA_1kg_reduce_file_15.txt.gz with replacing
                      Stack trace:
                      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: workspace_java/guidance_0.9.8/tests/test_1/outputs/associations/phenoA/EURvsAFR_for_1kg/Chr_21/chr_21_phenoA_1kg_reduce_file_15.txt.gz
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copyFile(UnixCopyFile.java:245)
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:579)
                        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
                        at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1227)
                        at integratedtoolkit.types.COMPSsMaster.obtainData(COMPSsMaster.java:142)
                        at integratedtoolkit.types.resources.Resource.getData(Resource.java:171)
                        at integratedtoolkit.types.resources.Resource.getData(Resource.java:156)
                        at integratedtoolkit.components.impl.DataInfoProvider.blockDataAndGetResultFile(DataInfoProvider.java:368)
                        at integratedtoolkit.components.impl.TaskAnalyser.checkResultFileTransfer(TaskAnalyser.java:469)
                        at integratedtoolkit.components.impl.TaskAnalyser.updateGraph(TaskAnalyser.java:428)
                        at integratedtoolkit.types.request.ap.GraphUpdateRequest.process(GraphUpdateRequest.java:63)
                        at integratedtoolkit.components.impl.AccessProcessor.run(AccessProcessor.java:120)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)ter code here
```

Comment: Version? Have you defined a shared disk in the resources.xml?

Comment: 1.4. Yes, there is a shared disk defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in the 1.4 release with the copies required to create file versions or move to the final location when using the shared disks. You should install a patched version.

```
wget http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/1.4/patches/COMPSs_1.4_08_update.tgz

tar zxvf COMPSs_1.4_08_update.tgz

cd 1.4_08/builders

sudo -E ./buildlocal
```